# Dynamically Populate ng2 chart in Angular 4

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

I have written a sample application to fetch data from service in json format and bind it to the chart on UI.

The problem is when ever I try to bind the data, it doesn't. I tried in many ways to bind data but was unsuccessfull.

Functionality is as follows:
Page 1: contains 2 dropdowns. 1 with Chart Type & 2nd with Sample Type.
On selection of both dropdown values, I click on a button which triggers a function fetchData() in GlobalService.

Below is getter & setter in GlobalService

```
 getChartData() {
  return this.chartData;
 }

 setChartData(response: any) {
   this.chartData = response.data;
   // console.log(this.chartData);
 }

 getChartlabel() {
  return this.chartLabel;
 }

 setChartLabel(response: any) {
   this.chartLabel = response.label.label;
   // console.log(this.chartLabel);
 }

 getResponse() {
   return this.response;
 }
 setResponse(response: any) {
   this.response = response;
   // console.log(response);
 }
```

and function goes like this

```
 fetchData(chart: any, sample: any) {
  console.log();
  const request = {
    chartType: this.selectedChart, // 'BAR | LINE'
    sampleType: this.selectedSample // 'COUNT'
  };

  this.http.post('http://localhost:22222/school/getData', request, this.options)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        res = res.json();
        const responseData = res;
        console.log(responseData);
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
          console.log('Data Fetched');
          this.setResponse(responseData); // Setting response
          this.setChartData(responseData); // setting data
          this.setChartLabel(responseData); // setting label
          this.router.navigate(['/gotoChartPage']); // navigating to next page chart.html
        } else {
          alert('Data Fetch Failed');
        }
      });
 }
```

Now my chart.html looks like this as mentioned in [here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

```
<div id='barDiv' class="onerow" *ngIf="1">
        <h4 class="m-2">Bar Chart</h4>
    <div style="display: block">
        <canvas baseChart width="800" height="500"
                [datasets]="barChartData" // --> This is where i want to update Data
                [labels]="barChartLabels" // --> This is where i want to update Labels
                [options]="barChartOptions"
                [legend]="barChartLegend"
                [chartType]="barChartType">
          </canvas>
      </div>
```

Then my Chart.component is as follows

```
  /*******************BAR CHART*********************************/
  public barChartOptions: any = {
     scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };

 public barChartLabels: Array<any> = []; // ["STD 1", "STD 2", "STD 3", "STD 4", "STD 5", "STD 6", "STD 7", "STD 8", "STD 9", "STD 10"]; Sample Data
 public barChartType  = 'bar';
 public barChartLegend  = true;
 public barChartData: any[]  = []; // [ {'data': [40, 32, 42, 23, 43, 35, 50, 48, 37, 45], label: 'COUNT'}]; -- Sample Data

 constructor(private global: GlobalService) {
  this.barChartData =  this.global.chartData;
  this.barChartLabels =  this.global.chartLabel;
}
```

My response from json comes in this format:

For Single dataSets:

```
{
 "data":
    {"data": [40,32,42,23,43,35,50,48,37,45], "label":"COUNT"},
 "label":
    {"label":["STD 1","STD 2","STD 3","STD 4","STD 5","STD 6","STD 7","STD 8","STD 9","STD 10"]}
}
```

and

For multiple dataSets:

```
{
 "data":
    {"data": [40,32,42,23,43,35,50,48,37,45], "label":"MVM"},
    {"data": [04,03,02,03,03,05,50,80,07,45], "label":"HVD"},
    {"data": [20,32,42,23,43,60,50,48,70,40], "label":"BMS"},
 "label":
    {"label":["STD 1","STD 2","STD 3","STD 4","STD 5","STD 6","STD 7","STD 8","STD 9","STD 10"]}
}
```

When I try to assign in this way, the chart doesn't come up. But if I hardcode the values in the barChartLabels & barChartData the Charts displays.

I also tried in this way

```
`<canvas baseChart width="800" height="500"
   [datasets]="global.chartData" // --> This is where I need to update Data
   [labels]="global.chartLabel" // --> This is where I need to update Labels
   [options]="barChartOptions"
   [legend]="barChartLegend"
   [chartType]="barChartType">
 </canvas>`
```

Help is appreciated. I am stuck with this from more than my brain can think of.

I came across this example on stack : [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078061/dynamically-updated-ng2-charts) & [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236883/ng2-charts-update-the-graphic-at-the-label)  But, its not the correct way to do.

I am wondering why the data doesn't get bind to the charts like this directly

```
   [datasets]="global.chartData" // --> This is where I need to update Data
   [labels]="global.chartLabel"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your global service holds the current data sets in the `chartData` member, and you read that variable once in your component's constructor. However when the data changes, the `chartData` member in your global service is replaced, but the one in your component keeps pointing to the original, so you never see a change.

You could use an observable stream in your global service to notify clients of change in data.